# FIBonacci sequence

Tags: code-golf, number, fibonacci

For this code golf, you will receive an input of a **fib**onacci sequence, that is, a normal Fibonacci sequence but with one number incorrect. <sub>See, the sequence is *fibbing*! Get it? `:D`</sub>

Your job is to find out which number is incorrect, and print the index (0-based) of that number.

For example:

```
Input : 1 1 2 9 5 8 13
Output: 3

Input : 8 13 21 34 55 80
Output: 5

Input : 2 3 5 5 13 21
Output: 3
```

Specifications:

- The sequence may start at any number.
- The first two numbers of the input will *always* be correct.
- Shortest code (character count) wins.

Comment: Does the input have to be space-delimited or can commas be used as well?

Comment: @Volatility Input is space-delimited.

Comment: The job is to find only the _first_ such number, right? For example, if you started from the right in the first sequence you could think that `8` is incorrect because it doesn't equal `9+5`

Comment: @LuisMendo There will always be only one such number.

Comment: @Doorknob That depends on which criterion you use. In the first sequence, 9 and 8 are both incorrect, as I see it (9 is not 1+2; and 8 is not 9+5)

Comment: @LuisMendo Okay, let me reword that: There will always be exactly one way to change a single number that causes the sequence to be correct.

Comment: @Doorknob Oh, I understand now. I think your rephrasing implies that the changed element should always be the _first_ that is wrong (and so my answer is valid)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### GolfScript (18 chars)

```
~]:^,,{^>3<~-+}?2+
```

The key to keeping this short is [?](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/builtin.html#%3f) (find).

Comment: +1 for the portrait of Fibonacci `~]:^,`

Answer (score 5):

### J, <strike>30</strike> 23

```
(2+0 i.~2&}.=[:}:}:+}.)
```

Answer (score 5):

### Golfscript, <s>31</s> <s>28</s> <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 23

```
~]-1%~1{)\3$3$-=}do])\;
```

Answer (score 5):

### APL (19)

```
1+1⍳⍨(1↓1⌽k)≠2+/k←⎕
```

Explanation:

- `k←⎕`: store user input in `k`
- `2+/k`: sum each pair of elements in `k` (i.e. `1 1 2 3` -> `1+1 1+2 2+3` -> `2 3 5`)
- `1↓1⌽k`: rotate `k` to the right by 1 and then drop the first element (i.e. `1 1 2 3` -> `2 3 1`)
- `≠`: find the place where these lists are not equal
- `1⍳⍨`: find the location of the first `1` in this list (location of the incorrect number)
- `1+`: add 1 to compensate for the dropped element

Answer (score 4):

## K, 32

```
{2+*&~(n@n@x)=x+(n:{1_x,x 0})@x}
```

Answer (score 4):

## dc, <strike>36</strike> 32

```
?zszsasb[lalbdsa+dsb=x]dsxxlzz-p
```

`dc` is a reverse-Polish calculator, so obviously you need to input the numbers in reverse order ;)

```
$ dc fib.dc <<< "999 13 8 5 3 2 1 1"
7
$ dc fib.dc <<< "999 1 1"
2
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, 70

```
for(n=prompt().split(' '),i=n.length;i---2;)if(n[i-2]- -n[i-1]!=n[i])i
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (<strike>69</strike> <strike>68</strike> <strike>61</strike> <strike>60</strike> 55)

```
for(s=prompt(i=2).split(' ');s[i]-s[i-1]==s[i-2];i++);i
```

---

(60)

```
s=prompt(i=2).split(' ');for(;s[i]==+s[i-1]+ +s[i++-2];);--i
```

---

(61)

```
s=prompt(i=1).split(' ');for(k=+s[1];k+=+s[i-1],k==s[++i];);i
```

---

(68)

```
s=prompt(i=1).split(' ');for(k=+s[1];k+=+s[i-1],k==s[++i];);alert(i)
```

---

(69)

```
s=prompt(i=1).split(' ');k=+s[1];for(;k+=+s[i-1],k==s[++i];);alert(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Awk: 55

```
{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)if($i+$(i-1)!=$(i+1)){print i;exit}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 66

My first attempt at an (somewhat) complicated Ruby program:

```
p gets.split.map(&:to_i).each_cons(3).find_index{|a,b,c|a+b!=c}+2
```

Comment: You can save quite a few characters if you replace `gets.split` with `$*` (`ARGV`) to take input as command line arguments instead of on the standard input stream. The space between `p` and `$*` can then also be safely removed.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 74

```
a=map(int,raw_input().split())
i=2
while a[i-2]+a[i-1]==a[i]:i+=1
print i
```

I had this solution first, but Doorknob answered the question about the format of input *right* before I had time to post it:

## Python, 66

```
a,b=input(),input()
i=2
while input()==a+b:a,b=b,a+b;i+=1
print i
```

Assumes newline separated input.

Answer (score 1):

**VB.net (77)**

Assuming the numbers are already in a IEnumerable(Of Integer).

```
 Dim p = xs.Skip(2).TakeWhile(Function(c, i) c = xs.Skip(i).Take(2).Sum).Count + 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab / Octave, 39 bytes

*Thanks to [Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin) for saving a byte! (`-` instread of `~=`)*

```
@(x)find(diff(x(2:end))-x(1:end-2),1)+1
```

This is an anonymous function that inputs an array and outputs a number.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##JcrBCoMwEIThe59ijruowd0YqEKh7yE5lCYLXvRSSt4@Rrz9fDPH9/f552ov51x9U2Hb9kRpM6NCuuQ9MQ@F5KpBuRfupBqtAoFiRsAT4iM/ml0FFfgJofl4q8K3V7i3yPUE)

Answer (score 1):

## JS, 52B

```
for(s=prompt(i=2).split` `;s[i]-s[i-1]==s[i++-2];);i
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 77 bytes

```kotlin
{val r=it.split(' ').map{it.toInt()}
var i=2
while(r[i]==r[i-1]+r[i-2])i++
i}
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
{
    val r = it.split(' ').map { it.toInt() }
    var i=2
    while(r[i] == r[i-1] + r[i-2]) i++
    i
}
```

### Test

```kotlin
var f:(String)->Int =
{val r=it.split(' ').map{it.toInt()}
var i=2
while(r[i]==r[i-1]+r[i-2])i++
i}

data class Test(val input: String, val output: Int)

val TESTS = listOf(
        Test("1 1 2 9 5 8 13", 3),
        Test("8 13 21 34 55 80", 5),
        Test("2 3 5 5 13 21", 3)
)
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val fails = TESTS
        .asSequence()
        .map { it to f(it.input) }
        .filter { (test, res) -> test.output != res }
        .toList()

    if (fails.isEmpty()) {
        println("Test Passed")
    } else {
        fails.forEach{ println(it)}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 45 bytes

```
{first :k,?*,(@($/=.words)Z-($0,$1,*+*...*))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpbCsIwFAW3cijBPIyxNzHig6jr8KcIGhCVSiJIKV17bPFrYGbet/Rcl1eHWUQofbyn/MHuoY9Ki5Ngy2C@bbpmeV4IVmtGWs2VMUZJOZR86VCxBuGAPoI1Q4XYJnACwWILjw3IcQ0@EZbgVvCjrSdn4cbD/wvflx8)

`$/ = .words` stores the words (numbers) of the input string into the pattern-match variable `$/`.  Conveniently, the elements of that variable can be accessed with `$0`, `$1`, etc, so `$0, $1, * + * ... *` forms the Fibonacci sequence starting with the first two input numbers.  The input numbers and the Fibonacci sequence are then zipped together using the subtraction operator (`Z-`), forming a new sequence which is nonzero only at the place where the two series are different.  Then `first :k, ?*, ...` returns the index (thanks to the `:k` parameter) of that location; `?*` is an anonymous predicate function that coerces its argument to a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

### Python (90)

```
a=map(int,raw_input().split())
print min(i for i in range(2,len(a))if a[i-2]+a[i-1]!=a[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica 59

Because space-delimited input is required, `StringSplit` needs to be employed.
The following assumes that the input is in the form of a string `i`.

```
s = StringSplit@i;
p = 3; While[s[[p - 1]] + s[[p - 2]] == s[[p]], p++]; p - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 48

```
f l=length$fst$span id$zipWith(==)l$1:scanl(+)1l
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ÆḞ€i$€In1i1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28Md8x41rclUARKeeYaZhv///4@20FEwNNZRMDLUUTA20VEwNdVRsDCIBQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 31 bytes

```
_!_!{_!~a+b=c|a=b┘b=c┘s=s+1\_Xs
```

### Explanation

```
_!_!           Ask the user for two umbers, assign them to 'a' and 'b'
{              DO
 _!            Ask for a third number (this will be assigned to 'c' on every iteration)
 ~a+b=c        IF the previous two terms add up to the third
 |a=b          THEN shift b into a, 
   ┘b=c            and c into b
   ┘s=s+1          increment s (starts as 3 in QBIC)
 \_Xs          ELSE quit, printing the step counter
```

I'm not quite sure if this is allowed; the sequence is entered one term at a time, and the program aborts on error, not after entering the entire sequence.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 0 bytes (content) + 52 bytes (filename).

- Filename (escaped): `\002._._X.w.c.t.v.m.v.+._.c.t.v.m.v.-\001.r.x.n.d.a\001.+.vX.a`

### Usage

- From stdin
- Must be an actual FIBonacci sequence
- Each integer are separated with blank characters

### With comments

```
XX.z
# Initial stack: F(i-1), F(i-2), i
# i is initially 2
.a\002._._XX.z
# while :; do
.aX.wXX.z
  # to: (F(i-1)+F(i-2)), i, F(i-1)
  .a.c.t.v.m.v.+XX.z
  # input is F(i)
  # to: F(i), (F(i-1)+F(i-2)), i, F(i-1), F(i)
  .a._.c.t.v.m.vXX.z
  # to 0, abs(F(i)-F(i-1)-F(i-2)), i, F(i-1), F(i)
  # if (pop!=pop); then
  .a.-\001.r.xXX.z
    # print pop; exit; fi
    .a.n.d.aXX.z
  # to F(i), F(i-1), (i+1)
  .a\001.+.vXX.z
# done
.aX.a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVh7V9rKFv@/n2JII5mQ5wAqEqNS8FrOUYrWuqyArhCCgiFwkqBo4Hz13j2TIBB6u267NDO//Zz9mIfPwdOvz59ty7L3bKe7388f5Ill9Z2CZZcKdr9I8jqxd0v6vrOX7@c/BU6IFGdqTEdW8Ix0PZ83nNlk7IfovPpQOT83qwYO3yYOenRCe@z1s1k2s8ejkeX1xCOt57xo3tR1Uf4oS7LZRLhZuf5qcjxO@JAyWSpgJJGP6EcqL@KBsuCWZn806rcP369rZl7XC0uw@e17/fb850P129XVafXaJEYLcXz0pfL968PN6dX3@rdGWXpbcMhEb6iTzbJVjdFkHAxm8Uz6Eovc/Q8JZzR1rdBBwRPjH09CGL6O/V4wcQdhNmu5AytAyiMS@IhIHH/CLQRToF8hm238OD@vXtTMMrOBqb2eETwN@qHBxojyJYBjP40R/1mklgm1nAFD@bHbO8pC6F8sF3EZ1LfcwOHm83UaU82kZ/PA6SEh0Gbam2YE8OtdE5jCd9ShQowLeJaiNhbxGJJQ8ZDyEk7JPPSRUg1Qu6UrBx0ktNperiPMH31ngtRYuXZf3OO1qFwx@K7RMLS2x@ZNMHevqm1P04xuxVjE09Y91UNIntcmmhGugyV9GyOE8No4Be4fbGOEgLSXZixtY0Tf5bVBmrGwjR0A30MaA8t2Ctvb38YIAeEgvb7CNkYIuPiSZtzbxogOEeun3da3MaJDxJy0jwfbGCFFXvPTpvPbGCEg/Zpm3N/GYL/godBSjKVtjOTBx7c048E2RvLgz3s6CfpvMHDHSi96dxsjBGIbpi0XtzGigzujdLz3tzGigzu9tOnSNlaE9EtpDFxUUlgB@DJpDLzm0xg4s0OxhTDHtpVsFz0xaUrWr1p0RptyZvSg/86odBurbbGN2x79rebaIq@1C@18m2jAFWhqDrp1ttnfZdfgM5HWep29vVu9jpaJGkbXBYUL4w2aXUOaobXuEyotcV5DPW1Dh@IhITHfuj@RO2AXPMCteAgu5E8QdeEp4YlxpOaAxDyLrcN6JsxNXpMp2gUXIMURzDJRAKOKNjG6l4DGbPIJKPhg7H0w9rTaknGDbUlJ4lD2DT6KzZ0gqhq2OMaNKkskrLDQ8pkGUNpeCynvnVyPagv9NQSWxOLTiRerMZIFbBOW03hxViy1AG/Llx8qVeZbeJnac5N4fIXI1CoQl1mSXBbZVdzi@JwlmthP7ErsSZL13wkKaHl0rCVEG/Sxa3Ud1zS5NuHEiK0EtyZjb/BgBy99xw9HUobfUTqUu02waGiPMQ@tx3ZE5PaCkpq4TRKate5SMO1ijiaEk6n0MYy5MnfCycysuEgMbvL/ibnGa13fsZ7ZBPJWwZw7Hk@QNw7RyArtp4H3yAGrsFyuhEWti4lI@RU2VuJJhk10NuZh/E8y3mFj4IE@ZD0o9Md@EiZwxjDESDA@GlRYCKL46z@NysWpKbThFqU@qA@36qtqq6H6oo7gRwJoNVOAiai@OlM9tadabCapL7eqJXyqfmtcnzauTUH4Ffi2KXw5Pas3IkiSFDhOTwx8uFBhNlz0p54dDsYeauKaGH1vPct/Y7Fj1gwYdiRpRT/FYuQ74dT3UEYCnhXlrxUF8COyovy9olB1K8L1BoGaVMga@RZfidGVCVzMDUUxEuarFc8UV8Vo4g@8EFVX6Bm@ku8@dMOF0R14zpF@zOtlZc2xr7EBnhisUO5ZFUpQLxwnbkAohrbN/6Dmp565ZruCL5YeXcw5yCxcnOildBCiNdMTWPrr08B1cAZCKo7XIwmTCMD5fIpvgbYieLgu38g12RVpFplgdGMCj@GaruM9hk/4RjRofdXhZls/NF1DnGJcM2EtQejjG7kuSTIRxX85ti7uuCYVS@XirrhYGRmA9SY@2zD8gC/kqnwn/xSjC5NTH8qoAQ1ioZ5jD0Zw04TFOo@OD9/JNOSMqgnixh34QH2hJQ7uFvcPq9ls9XC3JLKWMwCr/svdF1uF3Q4Pu8WdWSwq1UQ47kpgwaVYjBQhIFXTLOTFKGaBR0A48KbOgkacslYPiyXgOdrdFykUG1@ZjTWLP038U0RVpVgyaPaMJr7L/Vxbq72MfhNfbwQhWBJu15P1AjkZyjdiVDd1ZnFosjqG8A9p2cpDRemYNzRRdFbvMBDy0GHzYWct9P7KNEQUs/4Uc7QG1gy@rppm25sZvpSZrQy0I41wBmaXrERuzMtDypvI3qyE3v4odPR7ofcPN6gUc0PZcCVcLuYJetfcII2A9AzFguCN1MSUvkbsYgsCGpf4X7TCm9g6BnHJopEo3yYRMVY7Rs4kSj6HrUNdzNGcwXctqP@k9Q2TjrlNFouHOVeEigEznLoDR4QK1ciV0Z3jw41p8DIIQA1HC4UmxToeHrnHwx237O4My2yssTHkaBHvsOCZqXegHOBZh9lO0IcnF9vUubktcsLKuT5EYoMr2bO5@fYz6w@vLDM@nuI7AVy54Liir13F957J3J7CqCcgASn9/PIcgytME2dF@txbc8dhxRyfjxEULivoZ0kyJGl4iOkmTIsWQh6Hf5hMYSAav18GXW7PcR14EUOeoRWS7QkaRJLqhyAukbgl2ElTZxolAn0Sb/pSPO8sBIOeVPRPAXBpshH7c8GUdsh4RB@/APpb4CqGvSJSGsUNhvkcT@AhXoHX/aAnO@Fg5MgTezKVX4J3owdPeHE9B8U/P3VRaA1cuMgW1wJML9NRiV5o2LVJmFuvz6ALWaaSJ8X9YqmwVywhIbIkk9cXp41acmpYcAfgPv3f@U@0JtGhHw4SAAc@x0gCr8NtDP5xKIjTg7mdMSfzuijMZ5b/CDGoz1CSuRn69CuPCmgX/pMCypP/Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
δV≠İf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9yWsEedC45sSPv//3@0oY6hjpGOpY6pjoWOoXEsAA)

You know it's a good day when you get to use `decorV` in an answer.